# Concurency vs Parallelism in python multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, psutil

Summary:

Not so much of a problem just a question on python threading. It is my understanding that python threads can not be processed in parallel due to the GIL and all threads are run concurrently on the same CPU core. I wanted to see if a IO heavy multithreading program I wrote was becoming CPU bound so  I wrote some code to test this, however, I got some results that is inconsistent with my understanding of python threads. It seems that when I start multithreading it increases CPU memory usage across all cores, which was contrary to what I expected. Does this mean that CPU1, for example, is offloading some other background tasks to the other cores since it has an increased load from the multithreading program or is there some parallelism in multithreading that I was unaware of ? or is the psutils module not suited for this analysis and the data I have is not accurate ?

I have a multithreading program to download many different files where threads will spawn sub-threads. The program code is not really important so I will give the code I used to monitor the CPU memory usage per core.

You start the monitor thread prior to starting the main programs threads. The inputs are a threading.Event() (to kill monitor thread) and a max_time for timeouts. I also showed how to call it in the Example_thread class.

```py
from threading import Thread
import psutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psutil

class Example_thread(Thread):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

     def run(self):
        mon_event=threading.Event()
        mon=monitor(mon_event,(exp_time + 12))
        mon.start()
        """
        Insert desired code 
        """
        mem_usage={}
        mon_event.set()
        mem_usage=mon.evaluate()
        return(mem_usage)

class monitor(Thread):
    def __init__(self,event,max_time):
        super().__init__()
        self.event=event
        self.mem_usage_dict={}
        self.initial=time.time()
        self.max_time=max_time
        self.mem_usage_dict={'time':[],'CPU1':[],'CPU2':[],'CPU3':[],'CPU4':[]}

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.isSet():
            ls=(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True))
            self.point=time.time()
            self.mem_usage_dict['CPU1'].append(ls[0])
            self.mem_usage_dict['CPU2'].append(ls[1])
            self.mem_usage_dict['CPU3'].append(ls[2])
            self.mem_usage_dict['CPU4'].append(ls[3])
            self.mem_usage_dict['time'].append(self.point-self.initial)
            if (self.point-self.initial)>self.max_time:
                break
            time.sleep(7)
        print('Finished monitor')


    def evaluate(self):
        print(self.mem_usage_dict)
        #can plot here if needed...
        fig=plt.figure()
        ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        for key in self.mem_usage_dict.keys():
            if key != 'time':
                ax.plot(self.mem_usage_dict['time'],self.mem_usage_dict[key],label=key)
        ax.legend()
        fig.show()
        return (self.mem_usage_dict)
```

I expected to only see the memory usage for CPU1 (i.e. core 1) since the threads should only be able to run concurrently but instead I saw all the cores increase. In the plot below x-axis is time and y-axis is CPU memory usage in percent and CPU1-4 are each of the cores.

![plot][1]
[1][image]

Comment: Re, "all threads are run concurrently on the same CPU core." The GIL in C-Python prevents your Python code from ever using more than one CPU at the same time, but there's no reason why it would ask the OS to constrain it to run on any particular CPU.

Comment: So does that mean that different threads can run in parallel on separate CPU cores ?

Comment: No. As long as C-Python has the GIL, no two threads of the same process will ever run Python code in parallel. I'm just saying that the next thread to run may run on a different CPU from the thread that's running now, and when the thread that's running now gets to run again it also could come back on a differrent CPU. Assigning threads to CPUs is the operating system scheduler's job, and C Python has no reason to interfere with it.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up that confusion. One more quick question. The part of code I am monitoring in the program is essentially just FTP downloading files from different ip's so it is very IO heavy. In this case above it doesn't seem that I am CPU bound, however, the number of files downloading will depends on user input so I am not sure if it will become CPU bounded later. Do you think I would see performance/speed increase by spawning sub-processes (rather than threads) that go on to spawn sub-threads ?